# deploy laravel on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

My nginx and php have installed and run successfully.Enter URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/ in my browser will show 'Welcome to NGINX' page and when i run

> php phpinfo.php

on terminal will display all the settings in my php.ini. I tried to run MY_SERVER_NAME/phpinfo.php will keep loading without showing anything. When i try to open my website with the MY_SERVER_NAME i set in nginx.conf, it will keep loading without showing anything too.

My web.conf listens to port 80 and original nginx.conf listens to port 8080

```
server{   
    listen 80;
    server_name MY_SERVER_NAME;
    root /...../public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php=404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    } 
}
```

running sudo nginx -t display syntax is ok and test is successful

Comment: Your nginx server listens on the port 80 and you're trying to access it over 8080.

Comment: 8080 is the port that i wan to check whether my nginx has successfully installed, it has no relation to my website which is port 80

Comment: Open your `nginx.conf` file and check if you can find something like `include servers/*;`
This line tells the nginx to load all configuration files from the `servers` directory.

Comment: yes, i have that in my nginx.conf

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
server{   
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name SERVER_NAME; # server name of your choice. 

    root ROOT_DIRECTORY/public; # assumes the index.php is in public folder

    index index.php index.html index.htm index-nginx-debian.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php=404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; # assumes PHP listens on the port 9000
    } 
}
```

Comment: still doesnt load the page

Comment: i have even clear all cache and restart nginx and php

Comment: all your comments are what my configuration file is

Comment: What is the output of `lsof -i | grep php`

Comment: php-fpm   45930   xm    7u  IPv4 0x3e1b762573d49621      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm   45931   xm    8u  IPv4 0x3e1b762573d49621      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm   45932   xm    8u  IPv4 0x3e1b762573d49621      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)

Answer (score 0):

i was stuck with something similar, hope this link will be of help to anyone who faces anything similar
[Install Laravel PHP Framework CentOS 8 with NGINX](https://technowikis.com/14692/install-laravel-php-framework-centos-8-with-nginx#7-set-up-nginx-for-laravel-on-centos-8)

Answer (score 0):

For recent Nginx 1.18.0 or above, If you're planning to run on port 9000, then you need the proxy pass in your server block, this should suffice.

```
Server { 

    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com 
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    root /path/to/laravel/public/folder;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;
    ..
    .. 
    ..
    #any additional server params

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:9000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    # if only serving from public folder
    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/1710753062771683.sock;
         #nclude snippets/fastcgi-php.conf; #if any
    }
    
    location ~ "\.php(/|$)" {
         try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
         default_type application/x-httpd-php;
         #fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/1710753062771683.sock;
     }
   #end of serving from public folder
```

proxy_set_header param isn't needed for you i guess (if any specified in your http block)